# htaccess mobile redirect - full path redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

So what I am trying to do is send mobile users from the existing page to a mobile subdomain. Below is a working script that does this. However, I would like it to direct users to the correct mobile page. For example send www.domain.ca/pages/news.html to m.domain.ca/m_pages/m_news.html

The problem right now is that if a user enters for example from the RSS feed to the news page they are redirected to the main mobile page and not the news page.

I have a feeling that this is an easy question to answer, but am not familiar with the mod_rewrite operators.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.domain\.ca$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mobilecookie=true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.domain.ca [L,R=302]
```

and on the mobile site a cookie is set to true upon arrival.

My current naming scheme is that all page names and folder names are the same with m_ appended to the front. The folder structure is the same on both sites.

Comment: _"My current naming scheme is that all page names and folder names are the same with m_ appended to the front."_ -- That's bad & wrong if you have both mobile & normal versions of all pages. You should have 2 separate sites with the same URLs .. or mobile domain should be pointed or located in separate subfolder (but with the same page names) -- then such redirect will be easy to implement. But right now -- you will need pretty much a rule per page ...

Comment: Assuming I change the file names to be the same, how would I go about it then?

Comment: Like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.domain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]`. This will redirect `www.example.com/hello/pink-kitten.png` to `m.example.com/hello/pink-kitten.png` for mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of answers from comments:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.domain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

- Keep file structure the same on both main domain and mobile site

Use the above code and follow the bullet tip to successfully redirect